# Don't return null element based on a condition - Java Sprinboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am working on an API in JAVA-Springboot. Below is a sample response from the API. I am querying the database for records and if no results are returned, I am sending a message "not found in database". There is an additional field on the same level, which is "loaded", which is also getting populated with the null value. Is there a way to add a condition that if message = "not found in database", don't even return loaded field? I only want to return loaded = null if the value for that field is null in the database.

```
    {
       "requestID":"45",
       "requestDate""2021-10-16",
       "details":{
          "message":"not found in database",
          "loaded":null
       }
    }
```

EDIT: I don't want to use @JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL) because I want to return null if the database actually has null value for that field. But currently loaded is coming as null if I cannot even find an entry in database, which I want to solve.